# Tableau not showing the partition field (Athena Connection)

Tags: tableau-api, amazon-athena

I have established an Amazon Athena connection in Tableau and I can see all columns except the partition column (in this case this is date). I can, however, see the column in the table structure in Athena.

My colleague who is connected to the same Athena DB can see the column in his Tableau. Any ideas where the difference could be coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add the same problem. It came from the athena jdbc driver 2.0.2. I switched to 2.0.5 and it worked fine. I could see the partition columns

Comment: I can now see the partition column but when I try to execute a query in Tableau it takes over an hour (and I simply cancel it) for something really simple. When I use the JDBC 2.0.2. driver again, the query takes seconds. So with the new driver I am able to see the partition column but not the data itself. Did you have any similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

We faced a similar issue. What we did as a work around was to use a custom SQL on top of the table. The custom SQL was just a plain select * on the table in which partition column was not visible.

Post above, the partitioned column will be visible in the data source and also the reports will run fine without any errors, however i doubt that writing a custom would negate the purpose of having partitions since your entire table is now being 
pulled in memory rather than the partition only on which filter is to be applied.